# Mirror graphs in straight lines

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

a) Draw graphs for the following functions:

$$:\mathbb{R}^+ \cup \{0\} \rightarrow  \mathbb{R}, ()=\sqrt{}$$

$$:\mathbb{R}^+ \cup \{0\} \rightarrow  \mathbb{R},  () = −\sqrt{}$$

> What is the relationship between the graphs?

The graphs are related because they are both square roots of $x$, but one is positive and the other is negative. Not sure how I would draw it since we're not allowed to use a graph calculator.

The function $f$ is a square root function that maps the set of real numbers greater than or equal to $0$ to the set of real numbers. To graph this function, I was thinking maybe I should start by plotting the points $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$ on a coordinate plane. But from there I don't know how to draw something as the graph of the function $y=\sqrt{x}$ and $y=-\sqrt{x}$ respectively.

b) Draw graphs for the following functions:

$$_1: \mathbb{R}^+ \cup \{0\} \rightarrow  \mathbb{R}, _1() = \sqrt{}$$

$$_2: \mathbb{R}^− \cup \{0\} \rightarrow  \mathbb{R}, _2() = \sqrt{−}$$

> What is the relationship between the graphs?

The relationship between the graphs is that they are both square roots, but one is positive and the other is negative. Not sure how I would draw it since we're not allowed to use a graph calculator.

c) Draw graphs for the following functions:

$$h_1: \mathbb{R}^{+} \cup \{0\} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, h_1()=\sqrt{}$$

$$h_2: \{ \in \mathbb{R}| \ge 1\}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}, h_2()=\sqrt{−1}$$

$$h_3: \{ \in \mathbb{R}| \le 1\}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}, h_3()=\sqrt{1−}$$

> What is the relationship between the graphs?

The relationship between the graphs is that they are all square roots, but each one is a different function. Not sure how I would draw it since we're not allowed to use a graph calculator.

Answer (score 1):

As mentionned in the beginning of your exercice, you have to draw those functions. As you are not supposed to use a graph calculator, you can use the properties of the function $f : x \rightarrow \sqrt{x}$ (monotony, positivity, etc.) to draw it. Find some easy to calculate values f(x) (take some square numbers) and plug them into a graph.

You will then easily answer to the questions : "what is the relationship between the graphs ?" and understand the goal of those exercices.

Answer (score 1):

A point $(x, y)$ is on the graph of the function $f_1: \mathbb{R}^+ \cup \{0\} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f_1(x) = \sqrt{x}$ if and only if $y = \sqrt{x}$.  Since $\sqrt{x}$ denotes the nonnegative square root of $x$, $y = \sqrt{x} \iff y^2 = x$ and $y \geq 0$.  The graph of $y^2 = x$ is a parabola.  If you are not familiar with it, you can make a table of values by choosing values for $y$, then computing the corresponding $x$ values:

$$
\begin{array}{c c}
x = y^2 & y\\
\hline 
0 & 0\\
\frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{2}\\[2 mm]
1 & 1\\
4 & 2\\
9 & 3\\
\end{array} 
\hskip 1 cm
\begin{array}{c c}
x = y^2 & y\\
\hline 
{} & {}\\
\frac{1}{4} & -\frac{1}{2}\\[2 mm]
1 & -1\\
4 & -2\\
9 & -3\\
\end{array}
$$

Drawing a smooth curve through those points results in the graph shown below:

[image: graph of x = y^2]

Since a point $(x, y)$ is on the graph of $y = \sqrt{x}$ if and only if $y^2 = x$ and $y \geq 0$, the graph of $y = \sqrt{x}$ is the upper half of that parabola, as shown below.

[image: graph of y = sqrt(x)]

A point $(x, y)$ is on the graph of the function $f_2: \mathbb{R}^+ \cup \{0\} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f_2(x) = -\sqrt{x}$ if and only if $y = -\sqrt{x}$.  You could obtain the graph of $y = -\sqrt{x}$ in the same way.  Observe that $(x, y)$ is a point on the graph of $y = -\sqrt{x} \iff y^2 = x$ and $y \leq 0$.  Thus, the graph of $y = -\sqrt{x}$ is the lower half of the parabola $x = y^2$.

Alternatively, observe that a point $(a, b)$ is on the graph of $y = \sqrt{x}$ if and only if the point $(a, -b)$ is on the graph of $y = -\sqrt{x}$.  Hence, the graph of $y = -\sqrt{x}$ is obtained by reflecting the graph of $y = \sqrt{x}$ in the $x$-axis.

A point $(x, y)$ is on the graph of the function $g_2: \mathbb{R}^+ \cup \{0\} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $g_2(x) = \sqrt{-x}$ if and only if $y = \sqrt{-x}$.  A point $(x, y)$ is on the graph of $y = \sqrt{-x}$ if and only if $y^2 = -x$ and $y \geq 0$.  Observe that $y^2 = -x \iff x = -y^2$.  Therefore, you could obtain the graph of $y = \sqrt{-x}$ by plotting the parabola $x = -y^2$ (make a table of values if needed) and then taking the upper half of the parabola.

Alternatively, observe that a point $(a, b)$ is on the graph of $y = \sqrt{x}$ if and only if the point $(-a, b)$ is on the graph of $y = \sqrt{-x}$.  Hence, the graph of $y = \sqrt{-x}$ is obtained by reflecting the graph of $y = \sqrt{x}$ in the $y$-axis.

A point $(x, y)$ is on the graph of the function $h_2: \{x \in \mathbb{R} \mid x \geq 1\} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $h_2(x) = \sqrt{x - 1}$ if and only if $y = \sqrt{x - 1}$.  Notice that if we set $t = x - 1$, then $y = \sqrt{x - 1} = \sqrt{t}$.  Since $t = x - 1$, $x = t + 1$.  Therefore, we obtain the graph of $y = \sqrt{x - 1}$ from the graph of $y = \sqrt{x - 1}$ by increasing each $x$-coordinate by $1$, which has the effect of moving the graph of $y = \sqrt{x}$ one unit to the right.

A point $(x, y)$ is on the graph of the function $h_3: \{x \in \mathbb{R} \mid x \geq 1\} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $h_2(x) = \sqrt{1 - x}$ if and only if $y = \sqrt{1 - x} = \sqrt{-x + 1} = \sqrt{-(x - 1)}$.  Notice that if we set $t = x - 1$, then $y = \sqrt{1 - x} = \sqrt{-(x - 1)} = \sqrt{-t}$.  Since $t = x - 1$, $x = t + 1$, so we obtain the graph of $y = \sqrt{1 - x}$ from the graph of $y = \sqrt{-x}$ by increasing each $x$-coordinate by $1$, which has the effect of moving the graph of $y = \sqrt{-x}$ one unit to the right.  We obtain the graph of $y = \sqrt{1 - x}$ from the graph of $y = \sqrt{x}$ by first reflecting the graph of $y = \sqrt{x}$ in the $x$-axis, then moving the resulting graph one unit to the right.

You should learn the following graph transformations:

**Reflections:**

$f(x) \to -f(x)$ sends $(a, b) \to (a, -b)$, so it is a reflection in the $x$-axis

$f(x) \to f(-x)$ sends $(a, b) \to (-a, b)$, so it is a reflection in the $y$-axis

$f(x) \to -f(-x)$ sends $(a, b) \to (-a, -b)$, so it is a reflection in the origin

**Translations:**

$f(x) \to f(x - h)$ sends $(a, b) \to (a + h, b)$, which moves the graph $h$ units to the right ($|h|$ units to the left when $h$ is negative)

$f(x) \to f(x) + k$ sends $(a, b) \to (a, b + k)$, which moves the graph $k$ units upwards ($|k|$ units downwards when $k$ is negative)

$f(x) \to f(x - h) + k$ sends $(a, b) \to (a + h, b + k)$, which moves the graph $h$ units to the right and $k$ units upwards

**Dilations:**

$f(x) \to cf(x)$ sends $(a, b) \to (a, cb)$, which stretches the graph by a factor of $c$ vertically

$f(x) \to f(cx)$ sends $(a, b) \to (\frac{a}{c}, b)$, which stretches the graph by a factor of $1/c$ ($c \neq 0$) horizontally

Comment: Does $y =  f(x-h)$ send $(a, f(a))= (a, b)$ to $(a-h, b)$ or to $(a+h, b)$? It seems to me that the second option is correct, if the curve is moved to $h$ units to the right in case $h$ is positive.

Comment: @VinceVickler  Good catch.  Thank you.

Comment: Taussig. De nada.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you can sketch the graph of the function $ y = \sqrt x$ by computing $y$ for some values of $x$ and then joining the resulting points, as explained by other answers.

I also suppose you know, from elementary geometry, how to draw the image of a point or of a line under a symmetry about the $X$ axis or the $Y$ axis.

I'll talk of functions as set of couples, or, more concretely, of points , each point $P=(x,y)= ( x, f(x))$   having an $x-$ coordinate, and a $y-$ coordinate.

---

You can visualize here all the transformations and move a point $(a, f(a))$ on the curves : https://www.desmos.com/calculator/dx2gq8chat

<[image]>

***Tranformation of $y= f(x) $ into $ y = - f(x),$ say,  $y = - \sqrt x$.***

> You know that the point $(a, -b)$  is the image of point the $(a, b)$
> by reflection about the $X$ axis.

In function $ y = \sqrt x$ you have points $\color\red {(a, b)} = (a, \sqrt a)$.

In function $ y = - \sqrt x$ you have points $ (a, - \sqrt a) = \color\red {(a, -b)}$.

So, the graph of the second function is the image of the graph of the first , by reflection about the $X$ axis.

---

***Transformation of $y = f(x) $ into $ y = f(-x)$ , say,  $y = \sqrt {-x}$.***

> You know that the point $(-a, b)$ is the image of point $(a,b)$ under
> reflection about the $Y$ axis.

In function $ y = \sqrt x$ you have points $\color\red{(a,b)}= (a, \sqrt a) =  \bigg{(}-(-a), \sqrt{-(-a)}\bigg{)}$, for example $(-(-3), \sqrt {-(-3)})$, which is simply point $( 3, \sqrt 3)$.

In function $ y =\sqrt {-x}$ you have points $\bigg{(}-a, \sqrt {-(-a)}\bigg {)}= \color\red {(-a, b)}$

---

***Transformation of  $y= f(x) $ into $ y=f(x-k)$, say,  $y = \sqrt {x-1}$.***

> You know that point $ (a+k , b )$ is the result of translating the
> point $(a, b)$  $k$ units  to the right if $k$ is positive, and to the
> left if $k$ is negative.

In function $y = \sqrt x $ , you have points $\color\red{(a,b)} = ( a, \sqrt a)= \bigg{(} (a+k)-k, \sqrt {(a+k)-k}\bigg{)}$

In function $y = \sqrt {x-k}$ you have points of the form  :  $(a' , \sqrt{a'-k})$  . Now, every number $a'$ can be written as $ a' = a+k$ ( for some $a$)  . So you have points :

$(a',\sqrt {a'-k}) =  (a+k, \sqrt {(a+k)-k})= ( a+k, \sqrt a) = \color\red {(a+k, b)} $.

Consequently  , $y= f(x-k)$, if $k$ is positive , is the translation of $y= f(x)$  $k$ units to the right.

---

***Transformation of  $y= f(x) $ into $ y=f(k-x ),$ say,  $y = \sqrt {1-x}$.***

You know by Algebra $I$ that, for all numbers $n$ and $m$  : $(m-n) = m+ (-n)= - n+m = - (n-m)$   ( meaning that $(m-n)$ is the opposite/ additive inverse  of $ (n-m)$  ) .

So $y= \sqrt{(k-x)} = \sqrt {-(x-k)}$ , which combines (1) a translation of $k$ units to the right ( if $k$ is positive) and (2) a reflection about the $Y$ axis.

A point $\color\red{(a,b)}$  in $y= \sqrt x$ is transformed into a point $ \color\red {(-(a+k), b)}$  in $y= \sqrt {k-x}$.

Answer (score 0):

You should learn how to graph $y = \sqrt x$ you can start by plugging points of those $x$ values that you know are perfect squares, and then connect the dots with a smooth curve.

Next level thinking would say, $f(x) = x^2$ is a function with a graph that is a parabola.  $f^{-1}(x) = \sqrt x$ is the inverse.  The inverse functions reflect the curve across the line $x=y.$  Due to the symmetry of the graph of a parabola, you can also think of this graph as a parabola that has been rotated 90 degrees.

Caveat.. since $f$ is not a 1-1 function, we need to trim the domain in order for the inverse to be a function.  The graph of $f(x) = \sqrt x$ is the arm of the parabola above the x-axis.

Regarding the rest of the transformations...

$y = -f(x)$ will reflect the curve of $f$ across the x axis.
$y = f(-x)$ will reflect the curve across the y axis.
$y = f(x-a)$ will translate the curve horizontally.
$y-a = f(x)$ or $y = f(x) + a$ will translate the curve vertically.

$y = f(ax)$ will apply a horizontal compression (when a>0).
$y = f(\frac {x}a)$ will apply a horizontal dilation when a>0.
$ay = f(x)$ or $y = \frac {f(x)}{a}$ will apply a vertical compression when a>0.